# How to divide row and convert to dollar amount in razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I divide a column that I convert to an `int` and get the *dollar amount*?
For example, if `thisAmount=19`, then the output should be `.19`. With the current code below, it outputs `0.00`

```cs
@((((int)row["thisAmount"])/100).ToString("c"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you divide `int1` per `int2`, like `int1/int2`. you should cast `int2` to **double**, and the result will be casted too. so it's become like `int1/(double)int2`.
Change your code to :

```
@((((int)row["thisAmount"])/(double)100).ToString("c"))
```

Or use `decimal.Divide` function :

```
@(decimal.Divide((int)row["thisAmount"], 100).ToString("c"))
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: the second option would be the best approach